# Updating .XLSM file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsm

I am trying to update an existing .XLSM file using Apache POI. Every time I run my code I receive an error as shown below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[1] in the range [0,9] that is already written to disk.
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.createRow(SXSSFSheet.java:136)
at com.log.test.Test.main(Test.java:41)
```

Basically I wanted to use a macro enabled excel file as standard template , using java code i wanted to  make a copy of template and update the some sheet's columns data and save the file.

I am trying with  below sample code :

```
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("C:/LogTest/testme.xlsm"));
    XSSFWorkbook wb_template;
    wb_template = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
    System.out.println("package loaded");
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb_template);
    wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);

    SXSSFSheet sh = (SXSSFSheet) wb.getSheet("Asset Names");
    sh.setRandomAccessWindowSize(100);
    for (int rownum = 1; rownum < 10; rownum++) {

        Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
        for (int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 2; cellnum++) {

            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
            String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
            cell.setCellValue("hello");
        }

    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/output/new.xlsm"));
    wb.write(out);

    out.close();
    wb.dispose();

System.out.println("Done !!!");
```

Can this be achieved using Apache POI ? or i need to use some other libraries ?

[sample template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwcP3.png)

Comment: Does it work if you are using `OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream("C:/LogTest/testme.xlsm"));`? Seems as if the code tries overwriting the `C:/LogTest/testme.xlsm` file.